# How to enable breakpoint in Appcelerator

Tags: android, debugging, appcelerator-titanium

I'm building an app with Appcelerator with my iMac. Now I want to start this application in debug mode on my device Android. The application start, but if I try to set a breakpoint it not considered.
How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Debugging+Titanium+Applications) you can see how you can debug the app. It's like others JS application. Just use chrome with webview inspector